# Register with enable

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Here is the scenario:

I have a register with enable (call it RegA). The input put of RegA  is pulled high permanently.

Meanwhile, the enable line of RegA is connected to the output of RegB through some simple combinational logic.

Now in the scenario, on the next clock pulse the output of RegB will will go high **for just one clock cycle**.

My question is, will I see the output of RegA go high in the same clock cycle that RegB goes high, OR will RegA go high on the next clock cycle, OR is it possible that it may never go high due to a race condition?

From experience, I feel like RegA will go high on the same clock cycle that RegB goes high, however, I'm wondering if this is bad practice and unreliable.  I'm thinking there could be a race condition between the signal getting to enable line and the clock edge to RegA going high.  Since the enable line goes through some combinational logic, it would seem it would loose that race every time and thus RegA wouldn't recognize that the enable line is high in the same clock cycle that RegB goes high.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the enables you are talking about are clock enables? In this case you will get a one clock cycle delay before RegA goes high, if I understand you correctly. Explanation:

RegA will only react to clock cycles if its enable input is active when the clock arrives. However, since RegB has some internal delay, and since there even is some additional combinatorial delay from its output until it reaches the RegA enable, the active signal won't "make it" to RegA before RegA has already ignored the clock cycle.

This works both ways though, so the active enable signal will also **not** have gone away when the second clock cycle arrives, thus making RegA see the clock cycle and react to it. During the next clock cycle, the enable will be inactive again.

Remember though that a deactivated clock enable simply causes the clock input to be ignored, and the register will thus hold its value when the clock enable input is inactive.

This is not a race condition (unless you have a poorly designed system with a lot of clock skew for instance, but then you have a lot of other problems too), and can be reliably used - otherwise a lot of the stuff FPGA designers take for granted would be impossible to do.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your clock distribution is OK (for example, in an FPGA this will be managed for you by the tools) then you will get well-defined behaviour.

On the first clock pulse, the output of RegB will go high just after the clock-edge.  RegA will therefore have "seen" a low on its enable at the point of the clock transition, so it will not change.

On the next clock cycle, RegB's output will go low just after the clock edge.  However, this is too late for RegA as it has already "looked at" the enable signal (when the clock edge came) - it will see its enable signal is high, and will transfer the high input to the output (after a very short delay).

So, yes, you will get an extra cycle delay.